# XML attribute required with empty value

Tags: xml, dtd

I've set the attribut "number" to #REQUIRED, but is an empty value valid?

DTD:

```
<!ATTLIST person number CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

XML:

```
<person number="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an empty value suffices to meet the `#REQUIRED` constraint on an XML attribute.  The value of the attribute is irrelevant; the presence of the attribute is all that's required:

> [**Validity constraint: Required Attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#RequiredAttr)
>
> If the default declaration is the keyword `#REQUIRED`, then the
>   attribute must be specified for all elements of the type in the
>   attribute-list declaration.